# Finding formula for parabolic cone with constant ratio of volume to surface area of each circular cross section

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, volume

looking for some assistance with a problem I've been exploring with a friend for kicks.  I haven't taken uni level calculus or algebra in a couple of decades so I'm rusty!

I'm trying to express an equation for a parabolic cone (paraboloid?) where the ratio of volume to surface area of the circle through  covering every cross section throughout the height of the 'cone' is constant.  Presumably there is some parabola equation that creates a line that if spun around to create a parabolic cone shape would give this outcome.

Any takers?

Comment: What do you mean by volume? Is it the volume of the solid from its vertex to some distance $y$? And is the area that of the circular cross section at $y$?

Comment: Correct - volume from vertex to y. For each point along y-axis, the cross section at that point should have the same ratio of surface area (of the circular portion of the paraboloid only, not the whole surface area of the paraboloid) to volume.

Answer (score 0):

Such a solid of revolution cannot exist. Let the solid be generated by the rotation around $x$-axis of the curve with equation $y=f(x)$. Then its volume, from $x=0$ to $x=X$ is
$$
V(X)=\int_0^X\pi f^2(x)\,dx
$$
while the area of the cross section at $x=X$ is $A(X)=\pi f^2(X)$. If $A(X)=kV(X)$ for some constant $k$ and any $X\ge0$, then $A'(X)=kV'(X)$, that is:
$$
2\pi f(X)f'(X)=k\pi f^2(X).
$$
Hence, either $f(X)=0$ or $f'(X)=(k/2)f(X)$, that is: $f(X)=Ae^{kX/2}$.
But that solution doesn't work, because it gives:
$$
V(X)={\pi A^2\over k}\big(e^{kX}-1\big)
\quad\text{and}\quad
A(X)=\pi A^2 e^{kX}.
$$

Comment: Thanks.  I get the first formula (volume of object is equal to sum of surface areas of all the cross section circles making up the object).  I get the line under that which says the area at X is equal to PI x radius^2, where the radius is some function f as X varies.  I get a bit lost when you say '...that is: 2PIf(X)f'(X) = kPIf^2(X)...

Comment: @Paul If two functions of $X$ are equal, then their derivatives are too.

Comment: @Paul By the way: the solution I found would work if we allow for an infinitely long solid, i.e. if we make the solid start at $X=-\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT2:

(After OP comments on 26 Jan 2021)

Let $X=Z = r,Y=y $ symbol $r$  used for cross section radius.Surface area and volume of revolution are found. The ratio is a constant $c/2$, say

$$ \dfrac{\int\pi r^2 dy}{\pi r^2}= c/2  \tag1 $$

Cancel $\pi$ and differentiate with respect to $y$ using Chain Rule

$$ \dfrac{r^2}{2r \frac{dr}{dy}} = c/2$$

$$ \dfrac{dy}{c}=\dfrac{dr}{r} \to \dfrac{dr}{dy}= \dfrac{r}{c} \tag2 $$

Integrate with BC $y=0, r=a\; $

$$ \dfrac{y}{c}=\log \dfrac{r}{a}  \tag 3$$

Or

$$ r=a \;e^{y/c} \tag 4 $$

So it is an exponential curve rotated around $Y$ axis.

To verify the obtained result plug (2) into (1) and simplify

$$\dfrac{\text{Volume}}{\text{Cross-Section Area}}=\dfrac{\pi a^2 \int e^{2y/c} dy} {\pi(a^2 e^{y/c})^2} =\dfrac{ e^{2y/c} \cdot c/2} {(e^{y/c})^2}= \dfrac{c}{2} \tag5 $$

which is a constant. So the profile obtained by rotating around y-axis is an exponential curve. It is not a paraboloid of revolution, nor a cone. The ice-cream cup has bottom  diameter $2a$ with an upward flare, tallies OK. A rough sketch:

[image]

EDIT3:

[image: Effect of a start radius tooo small]

( EDIT1: First post before 26 Jan 2021)

To me looks that you mean  just a surface of revolution not any parabolic cone.

If a surface of revolution between two z- limits is considered, a single area for comparison.. am not able to figure out what it is. So I assumed that you refer to its  swept out surface area. With z-axis as symmetry axis, volume/ area ratio is

$$ \dfrac{\pi\int r^{2} dz} {2 \pi\int r \sqrt{1+r^{'2}} dz} =\text{constant}$$

where $r'=\tan \phi,$ the slope. Applying Quotient Rule reduces it to

$$ r\cdot \cos \phi = c$$

which on integration yields as solution the *catenoid* of revolution.

With initial condition $z=0, \phi=0$,

$$ r= c\;\cosh(z/c)$$

Comment: Maybe I can explain assuming the shape is a simple cone.  Imagine a cone with a vertex at the origin of the Y (vertical) and X and Z (the two horizontal) axes and rising up like an ice cream cone.  Let's say the top of the cone is 5 units up the Y axis, and at that point the radius of the top of the cone is 2 units across the X and Z axes.  In this case, the volume of the cone is V = (3.14 x 2^2 x 5)/3 = 20.93, and the surface area of the circle that defines the top limit of the cone is A = 3.14 x 2^2 = 12.56.  The ratio of V to A = 1.67.

Comment: For this cone, as you examine the areas of the cross sections for each point along the Y axis from 0 to 5 and the volume of the cone underneath each point, the ratio of surface area to volume will be changing. My presumption is there is some non linear equation that would define the line from 0 to 5 on the Y axis, as that line extends into the X and Z dimensions, where at every point between 0 and 5, the ratio of surface area of the circular cross section to volume of the cone underneath that cross section would be constant.  Is this a helpful clarification?

Comment: OK - a few more questions.  Forgive the rudimentary nature of my inquiries.

Comment: Feel  free to ask anything. All here like to help you.. appreciate if you don't give up before reaching the finish line.

Comment: For equation (1), why use C/2 as opposed to just C?  C/2 is still a constant, just like C, but was there a reason why you chose to divide a constant by 2?

For equation (2), you say integrate with BC y=0, r=a...can you explain this?  when y=0, r=0, v=0 and area=0.  As you move from 0 to 0.0000..001, then r, V, and area all become positive and increase from there.  Further, can you explain r = a exp(y/c)?  I don't quite follow...so, as you move up y, then r = some function of exp(y/c) x a...but what is a?

Finally, if I take your equations in (3), and I insert some sample numbers...

Comment: If y = 1 unit up from the origin, and assume c=3, then I get volume = 2.7182 and area=1.9477, which gives a ratio of volume to area of 1.3956.  at y=2, c=3, then volume = 7.3891 and area = 3.7937 and the ratio of volume to area is 1.9477.  So two strange things come to my mind: (1) the ratio is not equal to c, and (2) the ratio is changing as y changes.

Comment: c is any arbitrary constant. I took c/2 so that equation (2) looks simple and neat for an ODE. I have renumbered the equations. When $ r=a, y=0$ does not correlate to the ice-cream cone origin any more. The datum reference is changed and is now started afresh. In the second query, $c$ is constant, you are not allowed to change it. It should be 2 always.

Comment: Hmmm...OK.  If we assume that at y=0, a=0 as well, does that change anything (i.e., the shape terminates at a point at the origin, rather than a flat bottomed shape)?

Comment: From Equation (2) since the rate of radius increase is zero and start radius itself is zero the cone  volume never fills ..

Comment: OK - here I'm hitting a roadblock.  Can you explain equation (2) to me in words?  In the sketch you draw, the rate of change in r as y increases is positive (as y increases, r increases by an increasing amount).  If at y=0, r=0, if dr/dy is some exponential function, then when y>0, shouldn't r > 0 also be true?

Comment: Once I wrap my head around all this, my next question is, is there only one constant C = some number, for which the constant ratio between are of the circular cross section and volume underneath the cross section holds?  I.e., is it possible or not possible to have many different exponential functions defining the shape of the vertical lines of the object, each function representing a different constant ratio, C?  Simply said, is there one function where the ratio between volume and area, V:A, is 4:1, and another function where ratio is 2:1, another for 6:1, etc...?

Comment: Choose $c=8,4,12,$ etc...

Comment: OK - so I am thinking correctly, that the constant C can be any number, and the shape of the exponential function will vary based on the constant chosen - i.e., more or less 'flare' in the shape as you move upward.  What about my question above that about explaining (2), and that while at y=0, r=0, but since dr/dy is some exponential function, then as y increases from 0 to y>0, then r>0 should be true.

Comment: Answer to first part  is Yes. The second part for BC y=a=r=0 the flare does not begin at all. An example is ..of compound interest. If you invest nothing at start, the amount buildup will be nothing, the ice cream cone does not even start to fill. Btw I am wondering how the moderator is considerate with no suggestion towards a chat..

Comment: OK - sure, so theoretically, as you move closer to the origin, the exponential function limits and might never reach r=0, but practically, if you were designing a speaker with this shape (to go with your earlier idea), at some point, the exponential function would 'touch' and create r=0, I would think.  So, if we assumed at y=0, r=0.00000000001 (some tiny non-zero number), then the exponential function would start at a y=0, r>0  and then it would flare out (with the width of the flare determined by C) as you sketched I would think.  Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: (BTW, I tried to open a chat, but I don't have enough reputation points)

Comment: I have added a case of a loudspeaker with such a very very small start radius, and the program. See that it is too long and too narrow like a needle.

Comment: @Paul: We can adopt a catenoid flare  if you want to start with a zero radius and a small slope

Comment: @Paul: Normally such questions are unresponsive beyond a couple of answers, are down-voted or halted by the moderator. After study of differential equations a bit more I suggest you put a new question. I appreciate your sustained interest. Hope you get the message, Best of luck!

Comment: Ok thank you for your help. One final (I promise) question would be what the volume and area formulas in (5) and the curve equation in (4) would look like if you started with constant C rather than C/2.

Answer (score 0):

The ratio is a constant $c/2 =k ,\; c= 2k $, say

$$ \dfrac{\int\pi r^2 dy}{\pi r^2}= k  \tag {1a} $$

$$ \dfrac{\pi r^2 }{ \dfrac{d (\pi r^2)}{dy}}= k  \tag{1b} $$

Cancel $\pi$ and differentiate with respect to $y$ using Chain Rule as above  $ (u/v)'=0 \to \left( u/v \to u'/v' \right) $

$$ \dfrac{r^2}{2r \dfrac{dr}{dy}} = k $$

$$ \dfrac{dy}{2k}=\dfrac{dr}{r} \to \dfrac{dr}{dy}= \dfrac{r}{2k} \tag2 $$

Integrate with BC $y=0, r=a\; $

$$ \dfrac{y}{2k}=\log \dfrac{r}{a}  \tag 3$$

Or

$$ r= a e^\frac{y}{2k} \tag 4 $$

So it is an exponential curve rotated around $Y$ axis.

To verify the obtained result plug (2) into (1) and simplify

$$\dfrac{\text{Volume}}{\text{Cross-Section Area}}=\dfrac{\pi a^2 \int e^{ y/k} dy} {\pi(a^2 e^{y/(2k)})^2} =\dfrac{ e^{y/k} \cdot k} {(e^{y/(2k)})^2}= k \tag5 $$

which is a constant.

Comment: I have changed $c\to 2k $ instead of using same symbol and repeated in second answer space to be more clear.